# Explorer thumbnails for text files

Tags: windows-7, windows

How can I get explorer thumbnails for my simple .txt files? I have been asking this around for a long time, and only got two options, which were overly elaborated and ineffectual, and aesthetically horrible.

Hope anyone knows, as txt is the only common file in my system that doesn't show thumbnail previews in windows explorer...

Answer (score 0):

First, what were the two options? Sometimes there are limitations in Windows that you simply cannot change.

Second, have you already been to [this thread](http://www.winmatrix.com/forums/index.php?/topic/19751-get-thumbnails-of-more-file-types-text-document-and-3rd-party-file/)? Search for "Thumbnail Extensions 1.03" and "Free-Powerful Shell Extensions". There is a concise description of the first item [here on MSFN](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/121409-thumbnail-extensions-utility-for-windows/).

Comment: First link is dead. Second link goes to a post on MSFN, but that post just contains a download link that is also dead.